# Wordpress recreation from WP files & DB Backup

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, mamp

I made a new website locally on a mac with MAMP (the old one is still up and running).

I build it with this folder structure: ../wordpress/ Before Uploading, I tried to transfer the site in the root directory locally. I changed all links with blue velvet. Then however, I first copied the files in my directory to root and then changed the settings in wordpress (i read first you HAVE to change the settings for home directoy, save, and then copy the files). During that process something in my database got screwed up - and i think the Prefixes went from wp_ to wp_1. Once i figured that out i tried to change that in the database and then nothing worked anymore..

I have no clue of databases and I am super scared that the work of almost 5 days is gone. Any chance to recreate the site? I have all files in my directory and a backup of the database (only after things got weird).

I am making films for a living and I am really not a coder. So, any chance that there's an easy fix for someone who knows what he is doing?
I would appreciate every help!! :)

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look in `wp-config.php` for the `$db->prefix` variable. chances are it'll be wp_1 and needs to be changed too

Comment: I tried that already. Still doesn't run. By now I even set up wordpress from scratch and try to somehow get back the posts, theme, portfolio items and pages back into the new installation. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had two wrong (wp_1) prefix entries in my wp_options.php.

:)

Solved.